# How to get a list of printers on a remote computer?

Tags: powershell, network-printer

I am using this to attempt to get a list of printers on a remote computer:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_printer -ComputerName "$oldPcName"
```

The problem is I only get local printers, not those printers from the print server connected to the computer. How can I get a list of the network printers?

My goal is to get a list of network printers on a remote computer, remove them, and add different printers from a different print server.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7

To see networked printers, I read the registry

```
Function InstalledPrinters ($ComputerName)
    {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
        $InstalledPrinters = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Connections"
        $InstalledPrinters | Add-Member -Name 'PrinterName' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value ""
        Foreach ($InstalledPrinter in $InstalledPrinters) {$InstalledPrinter.PrinterName = $InstalledPrinter.GetValue("Printer").split("\")[3]}
        Return $InstalledPrinters | sort PrinterName | select PSComputerName, PrinterName
        }
    }
```

To remove a network printer:

```
rundll32.exe PRINTUI.DLL PrintUIEntry /gd /c\\$ComputerName /n\\$PrintServer\$PrinterName Gw /q
```

To install a network printer:

```
rundll32.exe PRINTUI.DLL PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\$ComputerName /n\\$PrintServer\$PrinterName Gw /q
```

Comment: [TechNet reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057(v=ws.11).aspx) for `PrintUIEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

This old question got poked by the community bot - The real answer is that *most* network printers (either connected through a print server or shared by another computer), are configured at the **User Session** level, and not for the whole device.

Powershell can connect in various ways like PS remoting or WMI, but it will always run as your own account by design. This means that when you or your script connect as an admin user, you will only see that account's connected printers.

In order to remove a user's network printers, you must run your script *as* the affected user. Some options for this are:

- Group policy: Under User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Printers
- Remote management tools like SCCM or Intune that can run in user context
- User logon scripts

The only way around this is the much more complicated process of [loading another user's registry hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056518/how-do-i-access-another-users-registry-hive-using-powershell)

Answer (score -1):

```
#--------------------------
#Set Execution Of PSScripts
#--------------------------

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force

#------------
#Turn Off UAC
#------------

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force

#------------------------------
#Enter The Name Of The Computer
#------------------------------

$comp = "Name of computer"

#or if you wish to be prompted for the computer name

$comp = Read-host 'Enter the name of the computer?'

#---------------------------------------
#Starts WinRM Service On Remote Computer
#---------------------------------------

Import-Module Remote_PSRemoting -force
Set-WinRMListener -computername $comp
Restart-WinRM -computername $comp
Set-WinRMStartUp -computername $comp

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

#----------------------------------------------
#Establish a PSSession With The Remote Computer
#----------------------------------------------

New-PSSession $comp | Enter-PSSession

#All of the replace commands are used to strip the extra characters and just #give a \\server\printer path return
#-----------------------
#Gets A List Of Printers
#-----------------------

$printers1 = Get-childitem -Path HKCU:\printers\connections | select name
$printers2 = $printers1 -replace '.*,,'
$printers3 = $printers2 -replace ',','\'
$printers = $printers3 -replace '}', ''

------------------------------------------------------
#To Replace The Old Print Server Name With The New One
------------------------------------------------------

$newprinters = $printers -replace 'oldserver','\\newserver'

#--------------------
#Gets Default Printer
#--------------------

$default = Get-itemproperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" | select device
$default1 = $default -replace '.*='
$default2 = $default1 -replace '()'
$default3 = $default2 -replace ',winspool'
$defaultprinter = $default3 -replace ',.*'

------------------------------------------------------
#To Replace The Old Print Server Name With The New One
------------------------------------------------------

$newdefaultprinter = $defaultprinter -replace 'oldserver','\\newserver'

#------------------------
#Deletes The Old Printers
#------------------------

Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer | where{$_.Network -eq 'true'} | foreach{$_.delete()}

#----------------------------------------
#Exits PSSession With The Remote Computer
#----------------------------------------

Exit-PSSession

#-----------
#Turn UAC On
#-----------

#Value = 0 through 4 depending on the level of UAC

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin -PropertyType DWord -Value 2 -Force

#------------------------------------
#Turn Off Execution Policy Of Scripts
#------------------------------------

Set-ExecutionPolicy undefined -Force

#####This is as far as I could get with it. I always turn off UAC and Enable Scripts in the beginning and turn them back on ant the end.  The summary of this script will give you the new network Printer paths and the users default printers.  It also deletes the users old network printers. With powershell versions before windows 8 and server 2012, you would have to create a logon script to add the new printers and mark the default printer using WMI commands.  Use could also use a csv file with a list of computer names as an input if you wish to run this command on multiple computers.  It would look something like...


$csv = Import-csv -Path pathofcsvfile
foreach ($line in $csv) {

#With a bracket at the end to run through each computer in the list...
```

This is all much easier with newer versions of Windows as they have the `Get-printers` cmdlet...

Hopefully that can get you started...  I would love to see someone finish this script as I have not had the time at work to do so...

Comment: I forgot to mention, you need to download the psremoting module from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-PSRemoting-Remotely-6cedfcb0 and place in the c:\windwows\system32\windowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules folder on the machine you are running the script from.

Comment: Added the modules to the folder mentioned, get this error: The specified module 'Remote_PSRemoting' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Comment: "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" This is extremely bad PowerShell practice - you should use "RemoteSigned" instead